# TinyMCE Bugs - INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a legacy internal system that uses TinyMCE but it has stopped working recently and I can't figure out why so I was hoping there might be some users who can help.

The system is an faq type and has 4 tinymce initalised textareas on the one page that when submitted, update the database.

The bugs in Chrome are as follows:

`Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1` line 110 in editor_plugin.js of the noneditable plugin which is

```
r = s.getRangeAt(0);
```

The other error is

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null` which is on line 1 of editor_plugin.js of the table plugin. Link: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:table

The strange thing is, if I click into the fourth tinymce box on the page and then update the content and submit, the database is updated fine so it's very, very strange.

I know it's very little to go on but the question is more in hope rather than expectation.

The last commit of the editor_plugin_src.js of the noneditable plugin is

`editor_plugin_src.js,v 1.1 2010/12/15 14:00:33 amcpeake`

I tried looking through the commits for this file on github but couldn't see anything that addressed this bug.

I tried downloading the newest version of tinymce aswell but that completely broke the system.

[image]

This is the full branch of code where the noneditable plugin is getting the error from the line mentioned above:

```
_moveSelection : function(e, inst) {
var s, r, sc, ec, el, c = tinyMCE.getParam('noneditable_editable_class', 'mceNonEditable');

    if (!inst)
        return true;

    // Always select whole element
    if (tinyMCE.isGecko) {
        s = inst.selection.getSel();
        r = s.getRangeAt(0);
        sc = tinyMCE.getParentNode(r.startContainer, function (n) {return tinyMCE.hasCSSClass(n, c);});
        ec = tinyMCE.getParentNode(r.endContainer, function (n) {return tinyMCE.hasCSSClass(n, c);});

        sc && r.setStartBefore(sc);
        ec && r.setEndAfter(ec);

        if (sc || ec) {
            if (e.type == 'keypress' && e.keyCode == 39) {
                el = sc || ec;

                // Try!!
            }

            s.removeAllRanges();
            s.addRange(r);

            return tinyMCE.cancelEvent(e);
        }
    }

    return true;
},
```

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code? Specifically the part where you try to access `nodename`? We can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's rare I ask a question wihtout any code but it's just the tinymce plugin and my initialisation code and that's about it, nothing special at all

Comment: Just post it, there might be a typo you're overlooking, something small.

Comment: Okay, and the `nodename` section? your JS seems to be trying to access that property on a non-existing object.

Comment: @cerbrus - can't seem to find where it's using nodename, going to do a search just now, give me a few minutes.

Comment: @cerbrus - `nodeName` is in the tinymce table plugin: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:table I don't see why this system needs it so I removed it from the plugins constructor in the initialisation code but the error is still happening....

Comment: ah, damn cache, it's gone now, so just the range error to fix now, somehow.

Comment: Okay, what's `s`, there? I suspect it's empty, hence the `INDEX_SIZE_ERR`

Comment: @Cerbrus to be honest, I don't know :/ it's tiny mce black magic, this is the plugin page: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:noneditable

Comment: `console.log(s)` before the `r = s.getRangeAt(0);` line.

Comment: `Selection {type: "None", extentOffset: 0, extentNode: null, baseOffset: 0, baseNode: null…}
anchorNode: null
anchorOffset: 0
baseNode: null
baseOffset: 0
extentNode: null
extentOffset: 0
focusNode: null
focusOffset: 0
isCollapsed: true
rangeCount: 0
type: "None"`

Comment: That looks pretty empty. So something's going wrong at `s = inst.selection.getSel();`, Couldn't tell you what is, though...

Comment: no problem Cerbrus, thanks for your help, will see what I can come up with.....